# Use Measurement for input in NSTextFieldCell

Tags: swift, macos, swift3, units-of-measurement

I want to be able to nicely use a Measurement and MeasurementFormatter for output and input with a NSTextFieldCell.

I am able to display the measurement correctly with...

```
let areaFormatter = MeasurementFormatter()
areaFormatter.unitStyle = .medium 
areaFormatter.unitOptions = .providedUnit

let area = Measurement<UnitArea>( value: 123.43, unit: .squareInches)

let editInput = NSTextFieldCell

editInput.objectValue = area
editInput.formatter = areaFormatter
```

This displays something like

```
123.43 in^2
```

The problem starts when I want to read this back in with

```
var inputArea = editInput.objectValue as! Measurement<UnitArea>
```

I think because the get Object value of the Measurement Formatter is not defined.

```
open func getObjectValue(_ obj: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>?, for string: String, errorDescription error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>?) -> Bool
```

Is my understanding correct? Are there any examples in Swift where this function has been defined for measurements?

Right now the user can edit the entire string including the text in the units. Is there a good way to block the units in the NSTextFieldCell? I would like the user to be able to edit the number but not the units and then return the measurement with

```
var inputArea = editInput.objectValue as! Measurement<UnitArea>
```

so this gets displayed

```
123.43 in^2
```

but only the 123.43 can be edited.

Comment: You won't be using `NSTextFieldCell` with iOS.

Comment: True. Trying to get this working on OS X before going to iOS. I assume I am going to run into the same problem there.